# Python - bubble sort take forever to complete

Tags: python

Doing this for school project.
I need to:

Execution of execution time measurements for given algorithms:

a. Measurements should be made for random sets of n = 100,
1000, 10000, 100000, 300000

b. For every n, sort should be looped 100 times and on
the end of the measurement results are averaged:

- Draw a new set of numbers to sort by quantity
  elements n. The range of random numbers 0 - 10000.
- Get T1 time.
- Perform a sort of a randomly selected set.
- Get T2 time.
- Carry out a subtraction of the time T2 - T1 and save the result on
  set of measurements

Is there any good way to speed up processing of that code?

```
import time


# bubble_sort
def bubble_sort(array):
    for iter_num in range(len(array) - 1, 0, -1):
        for idx in range(iter_num):
            if array[idx] > array[idx + 1]:
                temp = array[idx]
                array[idx] = array[idx + 1]
                array[idx + 1] = temp


def timing(func, b):
    timingList = list()
    for x in range(100):
        array = [randint(0, 10000) for i in range(b)]
        time1 = time.time()
        func(array)
        time2 = time.time()
        timingList.append(time2 - time1)

    return (sum(timingList) / len(timingList)) * 1000


def imlazy(func):
    print(timing(func, 100))
    print(timing(func, 1000))
    print(timing(func, 10000))
    print(timing(func, 100000))
    print(timing(func, 300000))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(imlazy(bubble_sort))
```

Comment: For one, is there a reason you wrote `timing` yourself, instead of using the standard `timeit` library?

Comment: It was in description of the assignment to measure it that way.

Comment: If they really asked you to do bubble sort on 300000 values 100 times, they're probably trolling you.

Comment: "bubble sort take forever to complete". That's about the correct description of bubble sort ;-) Use any other sorting algorithm if you want better performance.

Comment: If the assignment has you rewriting timing functions that are part of the language, I wouldn't waste your time with the course. But as others have said: bubble-sorting lists (or even more efficient structures) of this size is going to take quite some time even if you optimise your code, especially if you then run each one 100 times.

Comment: @Grismar Are you saying there are structures more efficient for bubble-sorting than lists?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode, yes, take a look at [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) for example. But bubble sort will still be.... well, bubble sort.

Comment: @wovano Just to be sure: You know that Python lists are what other languages call arrays, not linked lists?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode, LOL, yes, I understand. But lists come with some overhead, because of the nice duck typing of Python. And the array module is described as "Efficient arrays of numeric values", which seems to be very convenient, given that the OP initializes the lists with `randint()`. I have to admit that I didn't benchmark it, but generally speaking, using specialized array types (like `numpy.ndarray` to name another) is more efficient for large datasets of fixed type than using lists.

Comment: @wovano As that module's first sentence says, it's about *space*-efficiency. Here's a ...

Comment: ...[benchmark](https://tio.run/##5VRRa4MwEH73VxyMYtysq5bBGLj3wf5BKSGusQtolKiw7s@7i4lNbOlgz8uD5919d5f77rQ99Z@N3D63ahxF3Taqh17UPChVU4Ni8oDC2rUmZB9YlSnFTsA680KDILiDYiiKitMO/cGBl75OJlj0EgCeslEgeq6oHDC91KmPnFRcWhSsIY1hE8M6tRHnqMOXC5hTeBh9RGnutEPwHl6dAg@Q7pdYfXpet5B7MVcIL11@ke42dnIjXqdHdi74yBaEGDJtbppMgoRvYWws0b9lbbFTGS1Yxysh@RWbZ8/faDVjwY0X8kjKQX7EUNhYY3wXXY8JKhTETcFjM91sPCLngjv7sRCcBiIQY@bg4orIkaC/uFT3jDLRD1tqKoeXIt4SzPjsBt5dO2Fty@WBGPTaVMGWNUrxflASSDfUxEVE8Ah6nTxLBPdTA5YpUVfs@zQxZbtulW4zXCXbMoTVkson7DueOkgolazmlGrKcdNmFfIcQkprJiSlofs5UEfU1qPXlvcGH/3iy351njfGoUwv0Tj@AA) showing that it's much...

Comment: ... *slower* for this. (Don't we all love the comment length restriction...)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode thanks for benchmarking this (which once proves again that one must not make assumptions about performance without benchmarking ;p). It actually makes sense, since none of the `array` methods are used, so there's not that much to gain in this case... I'm glad I only posted this as a comment and not as an answer ;-)

Comment: @wovano Yeah I think it's slower because whenever you read from the `array`, it creates a full `int` object, so you're working with int objects anyway. That said, I think I once made the opposite assumption, someone suggested `array` and I thought it would be slower for that reason, but then I benchmarked it and it turned out to be faster after all. Don't remember why, might've been more cache-friendly or so.

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the general awfulness of the bubble sort, here's a slightly more efficient implementation:-

```
def bubble_sort(L):
    e = len(L)
    while e > 1:
        es = 0
        for i in range(e-1):
            if L[i] > L[i+1]:
                L[i], L[i+1] = L[i+1], L[i]
                es = i+1
        e = es
```